# GEKKO Optimal control. How to force values to be above certain thresholds?

Tags: python, gekko

So I am simulating plane flight. The plane flies certain distance (`path` variable) and then the simulation stops. The solver is trying to minimize the fuel consumption `(m.Maximize(mass*tf*final)`, by maximizing the mass value. The solver controls the accelerator pedal position (`Tcontr`). I need it to try and keep Velocity value V above certain threshold(for example >=100). What kind of equation I need to add for that to happen?

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from gekko import GEKKO
import math
#Gekko model
m = GEKKO(remote=False)

#Time points
nt = 11
tm =  np.linspace(0,100,nt)
m.time = tm

# Variables
Ro = m.Const(value=1.1)#
g = m.Const(value=9.80665)
pressure = m.Var(value=101325)#
T = m.Var()
T0 = m.Const(value=273)
S = m.Const(value=122.6)
Cd = m.Const(value=0.1)
FuelFlow = m.Var()
D = m.Var()
Thrmax = m.Const(value=200000)
Thr = m.Var()
V = m.Var(value=100,lb=0,ub=240)
Vmin = m.Var(value=100)
nu = m.Var(value=0)
nuu = nu.value
x = m.Var(value=0,lb=0)
h = m.Var(value=1000)
mass = m.Var(value=60000)
path = m.Const(value=5000000) #intended distance  travelled
L = m.Var()

p = np.zeros(nt)
p[-1] = 1.0
final = m.Param(value=p)

m.options.MAX_ITER=50000 # iteration number

#Fixed Variable
tf = m.FV(value=1,lb=0.0001,ub=1000.0)#
tf.STATUS = 1

# Parameters
Tcontr = m.MV(value=0.2,lb=0.2,ub=1)
Tcontr.STATUS = 1
Tcontr.DCOST = 0

# Equations
m.Equation(x.dt()==tf*(V*(math.cos(nuu.value))))#
m.Equation(Thr==Tcontr*Thrmax)
m.Equation(V.dt()==tf*((Thr-D)/mass))#
m.Equation(mass.dt()==tf*(-Thr*(FuelFlow/60000)))#
m.Equation(D==0.5*Ro*(V**2)*Cd*S)
m.Equation(FuelFlow==0.75882*(1+(V/2938.5)))
m.Equation(x*final<=path)

m.Equation(T==T0-(0.0065*h))    

# Objective Function
m.Minimize(final*(x-path)**2)
m.Maximize(mass*tf*final)
m.options.IMODE = 6
m.options.NODES = 2 # it was 3 before
m.options.MV_TYPE = 1
m.options.SOLVER = 3
#m.open_folder() # to search for infeasibilities
m.solve()

tm = tm * tf.value[0]

print('Final Time: ' + str((tf.value[-1])*100))
print('Final Speed: ' + str(V.value[-1]))
print('Final X: ' + str(x.value[-1]))
print('Final Mass: ' + str(mass.value[-1]))

fig, axs = plt.subplots(5)
fig.suptitle('Results')
axs[0].plot(tm,Tcontr,'r-',LineWidth=2,label=r'$Tcontr$')
axs[0].legend(loc='best')
axs[1].plot(tm,V.value,'b-',LineWidth=2,label=r'$V$')
axs[1].legend(loc='best')
axs[2].plot(tm,x.value,'r--',LineWidth=2,label=r'$x$')
axs[2].legend(loc='best')
axs[3].plot(tm,D.value,'g-',LineWidth=2,label=r'$D$')
axs[3].legend(loc='best')
axs[4].plot(tm,mass.value,'g:',LineWidth=2,label=r'$mass$')
axs[4].legend(loc='best')
plt.xlabel('Time')
#plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to implement that in Gekko.

**Hard Constraint**

The first way is to set the lower bound for the Velocity to 100 with:

```py
V = m.Var(value=100,lb=100,ub=240)
```

This is a hard constraint - the solver does not return a successful solution unless this is satisfied. This can lead to an infeasible solution, however.

**Soft Constraint**

If it is desirable, but not required for the Velocity to stay above 100 or there are problems with infeasible solutions then a soft constraint may be a better option. Set the following to implement a dead-band between 100 and 240:

```py
V = m.CV(value=100,lb=0,ub=240)
V.SPHI = 240; V.SPLO = 100
V.WSPHI = 1; V.WSPLO = 10  # penalty for violating bound
V.STATUS = 1; V.TR_INIT = 0
```

More information on this type of variable is given here in the [Machine Learning and Dynamic Optimization Course](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/ControllerTuning) with a [detailed description of the l1-norm objective](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/ControllerObjective).

Comment: If I try to implement the soft constraint, that you have showed, then tf value (that solver is using to control the simulation time) always chooses its upper bound value for some reason. If I try to implement the hard constraint that you showed, then it looks like the simulation just does not let that V value drop lower than is set, even though it is visible from other parameters, that it should drop. It just looks like the solver is not trying to keep it above threshold by manipulating the controlled variable.

Comment: You may need to balance `m.Maximize(mass*tf*final)` with the WSPLO by making WSPLO a bit larger or by including a multiplier such as `m.Maximize(0.1*mass*tf*final)`.

Comment: The program acts in a very strange way. It did not find the solution with m.Maximize(0.1*mass*tf*final), but it found the solution with m.Maximize(0.2*mass*tf*final). Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution - tuning the problem to enable a successful solution can be an art.